# Not showing custom 404 Error Page after PHP Upgrade to 5.4 from 5.2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am using following code in the .htaccess file to set a custom 404 page on my website,

```
    ErrorDocument 404 \my404page.php
```

This code is working if I request the webpage 
http://mywebsite.com/err (a non-existing page on the website), and in result browser showing the custom 404 page.

But, if I request the webpage http://mywebsite.com/err.php (added PHP file extension), the browser showing webserver provided default 404 page.

This malfunctioning is started happening when I upgraded the PHP from 5.2 to 5.4 on the web server.

I could not find any hints on the internet to resolve this problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does the apache error log show?

Comment: I do not see any error related to this issue on the error log file.